# Pandas Dataframe Datetime Indices Concat/Merge/Join corrupts index order

Tags: datetime, pandas, indexing, dataframe, corrupt

Consider 2 .csv files containing waterlevel data with a DateTime index. Can be dowloaded from:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/50zaz9ore00j7rp/AAA2MhNrNMRImoSBWWcUBNp4a?dl=0

Imported as follows:

```
pbn61 = pd.read_csv('3844_61.csv, 
                                 index_col = 0, 
                                 delimiter = ';', 
                                 dayfirst = True, 
                                 usecols = ['Datumtijd','DisplayWaarde']
                   )
```

*Same for the 2nd file. Global variable 'pbn65'.*

Now I want to merge these 2 DataFrames such that I can plot both dataseries in one graph. Reason for this is that I have about 50 of these files and neither of them have the same starting date and/or time. So merging some will greatly reduce the amount of graphs I end up with.

Now I only want the data that is available in both series, since only then the data becomes relevant for research. Therefore I use the following code(s):

```
pbn65.columns = ['DisplayWaarde2']

result1 = pd.merge(pbn61,pbn65, left_index = True, right_index = True, how='inner')
result2 = pbn65.join(pbn61, how = 'inner')

pd.set_option('max_rows', 25000)
result2
```

*I needed to rename one column in order to make sure it could join. Increased max rows to show counting error*

Both ways result in the same issue. That is that the index is put in a wrong order. Now this is probably because the index is a DateTime of the form

```
DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM
```

and joining/merging causes pandas to count Decimal instead of DateTime.

Concatenating both DataFrames gives the following error:

```
result3 = pd.concat([pbn61,pbn65], axis = 1, join = 'inner')
result3

Shape of passed values is (2, 20424), indices imply (2, 19558)
```

Which is exactly the length of the resulting DataFrame using merge/join.

Is there a way around this issue?

P.S. I would like to keep a DateTime index since I need to have a time indication for evaluation.

P.P.S. Most files contain duplicate indices. Trying to use `index.drop_duplicate` seems to do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

```
pbn61 = pd.read_csv('3844_61.csv', 
                                 index_col = 0, 
                                 delimiter = ';', 
                                 dayfirst = True, 
                                 usecols = ['Datumtijd','DisplayWaarde'],
                                 parse_dates = [0],
                   )

pbn65 = pd.read_csv('3847_65.csv', 
                                 index_col = 0, 
                                 delimiter = ';', 
                                 dayfirst = True, 
                                 usecols = ['Datumtijd','DisplayWaarde'],
                                 parse_dates = [0],
                   )

pbn61 = pbn61.groupby(level=0).first()
pbn65 = pbn65.groupby(level=0).first()

result = pd.concat([pbn61, pbn65], axis=1).dropna()
```

#### Explanation

```
                                 parse_dates = [0],
```

parse_dates specifies which column should be parsed as a date

```
pbn61 = pbn61.groupby(level=0).first()
```

this takes care of duplicate indices.  `drop_duplicates` takes care of duplicated records.

```
result = pd.concat([pbn61, pbn65], axis=1).dropna()
```

This merges the two.  I find this more intuitive.  There are many ways to do this.

#### Demonstration

```
result.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. I totally forgot about 'parse_dates'. That little line fixed it. Many thanks. However is it correct that including 'parse_dates' greatly increases processing time? I have 63 files that need to be processed with 'parse_dates', all around 20.000 in rows. I measured it and for 10 and 20 it took 40 and 80 seconds respectively. Might there be a faster way? I will post the full code as an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

@piRSquared
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import glob
    pd.**version**

```
Files = glob.glob('Peilbuizen/*.csv') 

def Invoer(F):
    F = Files
    for i in range(len(Files)):
        globals()['pbn%s' % Files[i][16:-1-3]] = pd.read_csv(Files[i], 
                                                             index_col = 0,
                                                             delimiter = ';',
                                                             dayfirst = True,
                                                             usecols = ['Datumtijd','DisplayWaarde'],
                                                             parse_dates =[0]
                                                            )

Invoer(Files)

pbn11 = pbn11.groupby(level = 0).first()
pbn13 = pbn13.groupby(level = 0).first()

result = pd.concat([pbn11, pbn13], axis = 1).dropna()
result.plot()
```

I updated the dropbox folder to 10 files for experiments. Creating a folder called "Peilbuizen" within the python save directory will create the globals.